# How to ensure child entities only have query methods in an aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, domain-driven-design, entity, aggregateroot

I have been reading things about DDD, aggregates and entities and a doubt has come up. Let's say I have the following entity:

```py
    class AnEntity:
          name: str
          
          # command / mutator method
          def change_name(self, new_name: str):
               self.name = new_name

          # query method
          def read_name(self) -> str:
               return self.name
```

And that I have the following aggregate containing that entity:

```py
class AnAggregate:
        root_id: Id
        an_entity: AnEntity

        def change_name(self, name: str):
            if len(name) < 10:
                raise Exception('Name must be longer')
            self.name = name
```

Now, supposedly, the theory says that aggregates should:

- Contain command / query methods.
- Only query methods should be available on child entities

So in my example, `AnAggregate` has a child entity called `an_entity`. So if you do:

```py
an_aggregate = AnAggregate(rood_id=Id('29839afef'), AnEntity(name='name longer than 10 characters'))

# I can modify the child entity, skipping the consistency boundary of the aggregate
an_aggregate.an_entity.change_name('invalid')
```

So my question is, how do I avoid this case using code? Is there a way to protect the entity?

Comment: I have no idea where "Only query methods should be available on child entities" comes from -- I've never seen anybody advocate for that constraint on a design.

Comment: https://av.tib.eu/media/44889 -> Minute 30:18

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado I also don't think there is such a rule (I couldn't hear it in minute 30:18 btw). I think it's just a convenience when coding aggregates. In fact, in minute 26:30 he says "you can put mutating commands on the child entities but then it gets more awkward to maintain consistency amongs the other entities within that aggregate".  As this is more of a code styling, it'll depend on the team that's working on the project. You can simply write it in the coding style guide or enforce it with a custom rule in your code linter (a bit overkill imo).

Comment: Oh you are totally right. I was looking at the slides only because I heard the talk some time ago. Thanks!